# Whats wrong with this mysql query syntax?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO group (name, des, tags, creator, cdate) VALUES ('$gname', '$gdes', '$gtags', '$creator', '$date')") or die (mysql_error());
```

I keep getting a syntax error...
i've been using the same method forever, whats wrong with it?

the variables:

```
$gname = $_POST['gname'];
$gdes = $_POST['gdes'];
$gtags = $_POST['gtags'];
$date = time();
$creator = $_SESSION['username'];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 5):

Post the Syntax Error....!!

But Ill have a guess, group is a mysql keyword. Try:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `group` (name, des, tags, creator, cdate) VALUES ('$gname', '$gdes', '$gtags', '$creator', '$date')") or die (mysql_error())
```

Note the backticks around the group table name. This allows you to use mysql reserved keywords as your own table names

Comment: It is keyword for sure. :)

Comment: Removed the uncertainty ;)

Comment: i kept getting a"theres a mysql sytax error"... and you are right, that worked! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO group (name, des, tags, creator, cdate) VALUES ('$gname',
   '$gdes', '$gtags', '$creator', '$date')", $connect) or die (mysql_error());
```

or

```
$sql="insert sql";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$connect)or die ("cannot insert".mysql_error());
Note: $connect means connection string
```

Try this   you just copy the sql and direct enter to db, if it works that mean error not 
   in ur sql

Answer (score 0):

you are using a keyword group, which is a reserved MySQL keyword,
I am sure this is the cause of your problem, Either change the name of your table or use it as follow...
 `group`